# Recursion: printing implied parenthesis

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am trying to print all the parenthesis but I am stuck with printing only one output instead of all the implied parenthesis.

How to show all possible implied parenthesis? [From here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/49918/36212) I got the idea.

I am not able to get the ways to print all the implied parenthesis.

```
def add_up(exp):
        operators = ["+", "/", "*", "-"]
        if len(exp) == 1:
            return exp
        result = ""
        for i in range(0, len(exp)):
            if exp[i] in operators:
                left = add_up(exp[0:i])
                right = add_up(exp[i+1:len(exp)])
                result = "(" + left + exp[i] + right + ")"
        return result

print(add_up("3*4+5"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns a single result, whereas the solution consists of several possible results. And when you recurse, the left and right branches may yield more than one result, too, of course.

You can fix that by turning your function into a generator and then looping over the results:

```
operators = ["+", "/", "*", "-"]

def add_up(exp):
    if len(exp) == 1:
        yield exp

    for i in range(0, len(exp)):
        if exp[i] in operators:
            for left in add_up(exp[:i]):
                for right in add_up(exp[i + 1:]):
                    yield "(" + left + exp[i] + right + ")"

for e in add_up("1+2*3+4"):
    print e, ':', eval(e)
```

Alternatively (and more verbosely), you can make the results lists:

```
def add_up(exp):
    if len(exp) == 1:
        return [exp]

    result = []

    for i in range(0, len(exp)):
        if exp[i] in operators:
            for left in add_up(exp[:i]):
                for right in add_up(exp[i + 1:]):
                    result += ["(" + left + exp[i] + right + ")"]

    return result
```